# column visibility: how to make few columns hidden by default in list view

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have displayed few column data in view using setColumns method like this:

```
$this->crud->setColumns([

                    (['name'=>'expire_date','lable'=>'Expire Date']),
                    (['name'=>'username','lable'=>'User']),
                    (['name'=>'prize_id','lable'=>'Prize']), /* New Column(must be hidden by default) */
                    (['name'=>'gifted_from','lable'=>'Gifted From'])  /* New Column(must be hidden by default) */
]);
```

What I expected to happen:
now in the same list I want to add few more columns to be shown in list view. But by default this columns should be hidden in list view and what I expect that new added hidden columns (in the above list) i can make visible through `column visibility` options provided through `$this->crud->enableExportButtons();`

Is there any way to do this in laravel backpack?

Answer (score 2):

You would add the fields you want hidden to the `hidden` property on the model:

```
/** 
  * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
  * 
  * @var array
  */
 protected $hidden = ['attribute'];
```

Then you can temporarily make fields visible by calling the `makeVisible` method:

```
$user->makeVisible('attribute')
```

See the docs on [Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit later but you can do `'visibleInTable' => false` for a column you want to hide by default. You'll be able to make it visible in `column visibility` options.

For example:

```
[
    'name' => 'email',
    'label' => "Username",
    'visibleInTable' => false,
],
```